# Getting data from a services Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, xcode

I have got a small problem with the below service data

```
{
    "DataTable": {
        "DataList1": {

            "StudentName": "Rakesh",
            "StudentId": "13",
            "StudentAge": "19",
            "StudentAddress": "NewYork",
        },
        "DataList2": [{
            "TeacherName": "Abhinav",
            "TeacherId": "309",
            "TeacherAge": "34",
            "TeacherAddress": "NewYork",
        }]
    }
}
```

i Can get the data from DataList1 and cannot know how to get the data from DataList2. Below is the code what i have tried. Please help to find out the solution. Thanks in Advance

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [jsonArray removeAllObjects];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.responseData = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary *sdf = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"DataTable"];
    NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (([(NSString*)sdf isEqual: [NSNull null]])) {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Information" message:@"Currently there are no Data" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert setTag:1];
        [alert show];
    }else {

        [myArray addObject:[sdf objectForKey:@"DataList1"]];

        jsonArray=[myArray mutableCopy];
        refilldict=[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *keys = [refilldict allKeys];
        for(int p=0 ; p<[keys count]; p++ )
        {
            NSString *value=[refilldict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:p]];
            if ([value isEqual: [NSNull null]]||[value length]==0) {

                [refilldict setValue:@"" forKey:[keys objectAtIndex:p]];

            }

        }
 lblStudentName.text = [refilldict objectForKey:@"StudentName"];
        lblStudentId.text = [refilldict objectForKey:@"StudentId"];
        lblStudentAge.text = [refilldict objectForKey:@"StudentAge"];

        lblStudentAddress.text = [refilldict objectForKey:@"StudentAddress"];
}
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [HUD hide:YES];
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    HUD=nil;

}
```

Comment: You can loop through `sdf.allKeys` to extract data from dictionary key-value like normal array, you currently only get value from `DataList1`

Comment: Your code is messy: `if (([(NSString*)sdf isEqual: [NSNull null]]))`: Why the cast? Why double parenthesis? `NSMutableDictionary *sdf = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"DataTable"];` I don't know what does `-JSONValue`, but are you sure that `sdf` is mutable, ie `[(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"DataTable"]` is mutable? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get easily like

```
[myArray addObject:[sdf objectForKey:@"DataList1"]];
```

> its started with array of dictionary , so you need to store your second object to array and take from index.

```
  NSArray *temp =  [sdf objectForKey:@"DataList2"];
  if(temp.count >0)
   {
    lblTeacherName.text = temp[0][@"TeacherName"];
    lblTeacherId.text = temp[0][@"TeacherId"];
    lblTeacherAge.text = temp[0][@"TeacherAge"];
    lblTeacherAddress.text = temp[0][@"TeacherAddress"];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the bellow code and pass your Initial Json dictionary in it.

```
-(void)parseJsonData:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary{

    for(int i=0;i<[jsonDictionary allKeys].count;i++){

        NSString *keyName = [[jsonDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:i];
        id objValue = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:keyName];

        if([objValue isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){

            NSArray *dataList2Array = (NSArray *)objValue;
            NSLog(@"DataList2 Is :--%@",dataList2Array);
        }
        else {

            NSDictionary *dataList1 = (NSDictionary *)objValue;
            NSLog(@"DataList1 Is :--%@",dataList1);
        }
    }
}
```